# Can a computer algebra system help me with this group theory problem?

Tags: group-theory, computer-algebra-systems, gap, computational-algebra

I have a problem in group theory which gave me the impression to be tractable by computer algebra methods. I have never used computer algebra systems and started reading into GAP. Now after several days I am thoroughly confused by specific questions on what the GAP commands actually do.

Before investing more time in learning this, I would like to know from more experienced computer algebra users, whether a computer algebra system can in principle help me with this problem at all.

Probably many of the details of the problem are irrelevant, but I cannot judge which ones, so I will expose the whole problem.

Let m,a,f be natural numbers, m even, a > 1, f odd and congruent 1
modulo $2^{2a-1}$ (these restrictions are probably not so important).
We have a group G given by generators $x_1, ... , x_{m+2}$ and the
single relation
$x_1^{2+2a}[x_1,x_2][x_3,x_4][x_5,x_6]...[x_{m+1},x_{m+2}]=1$.  (the
brackets denote commutators)
Now we look at the normal subgroup N generated by $x_1, x_2, x_3^f, x_4,
..., x_{m+2}$. It admits a presentation as a group (not as a normal
subgroup) with generators  $x_3^f$ and the conjugates of $x_1, x_2, x_4,
..., x_{m+2}$ by $x_3^i$ $(i=0...f-1)$ and the $f$ relations given by
conjugating the above single relation with $x_3^i$ $(i=0...f-1)$ (Since the commutator [$x_3$, $x_4$] occurs in there, and $x_3$ is not an element of the subgroup, it is not immediately clear that these are relations between elements of the subgroup, but it is true). We can further pass to the quotient $N / [[N,N],N]$ and get an induced presentation of this.

Now one can show that $N / [[N,N],N]$, also admits a presentation by
generators $y_0, ..., y_{f-1}, z_0, ..., z_{f-1}, x_3^f, w, u_{i,j} (0
\leq i \leq f-1, 5 \leq j \leq m+2)$ subject to the single relation

$y_{f-1}^{2+2a} \cdot [y_{f-1}, z_{f-1}] \cdot [x_3^f, w] \cdot
\Pi_{v=0}^{f-2}[y_v, z_{v-1}^{-1} z_v y_{v+1}^{(1+2^{a-1})(1+2^a)}]
\cdot \Pi_{v=0}^{f-1}(\Pi_{r=3}^{m+2/2}[u_{v,2r-1}, u_{v,2r}]) = 1$

I need to find such $y_s,z_t,w,u_{i,j}$, expressed in
terms of the original generators $x_1,...x_{m+2}$.

I have no idea how feasible it is to answer this
with computer help. In Magma, to which I have no access, there seems to be a function searching for isomorphisms between given groups. I could maybe use this to look for an isomorphism between the groups given by the two presentations above.
After having read enough of the GAP manual, I have the impression that GAP can not help me at all with this problem. Am I right? But maybe the problem is too complex for computer algebra at all? Or one needs the groups given in a specific way which I don't have? In my first steps in GAP I kept running into  these kinds of problem and now would like to ask whether I can hope for a solution at all. Welcome answers would be: A "Yes" or "No", if "No", then a reason why.  If "Yes" then an indication which computer algebra system could help me; if there is a freely available one, then this would be preferred. Of course I wouldn't mind an outline of how to go about, too :-)

Thanks a lot!

---

Summary of the smallest sensible case ($m=4, f=9, a=2$ in the above description):

I have a group $G$ with 38 generators $y_0,y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4,y_5,y_6,y_7,y_8,x,w,z_0,z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4,z_5,z_6,z_7,z_8, u_{0,5},u_{1,5},u_{2,5},u_{3,5},u_{4,5},u_{5,5},u_{6,5},u_{7,5},u_{8,5},u_{0,6},u_{1,6},u_{2,6},u_{3,6},u_{4,6},u_{5,6},
u_{6,6},u_{7,6},u_{8,6}$ subject to the single relation

$y_{8}^{6} \cdot [y_{8}, z_{8}] \cdot [x, w] \cdot
\Pi_{v=0}^{7}[y_v, z_{v+1}^{-1} z_v y_{v+1}^{15}]
\cdot \Pi_{v=0}^{8}[u_{v,5}, u_{v,6}] = 1$.

Now I set $N:=G/G^{2^6}[G^{2^5}[G,G],G]$. (I found functions in GAP and Magma doing this quotient operation)

I have a second group $H$ with 46 generators 
$x_{1,0},x_{1,1},x_{1,2},x_{1,3},x_{1,4},x_{1,5},x_{1,6},x_{1,7},x_{1,8},
x_{2,0},x_{2,1},x_{2,2},x_{2,3},x_{2,4},x_{2,5},x_{2,6},x_{2,7},x_{2,8},
x_{3},
x_{4,0},x_{4,1},x_{4,2},x_{4,3},x_{4,4},x_{4,5},x_{4,6},x_{4,7},x_{4,8},
x_{5,0},x_{5,1},x_{5,2},x_{5,3},x_{5,4},x_{5,5},x_{5,6},x_{5,7},x_{5,8},
x_{6,0},x_{6,1},x_{6,2},x_{6,3},x_{6,4},x_{6,5},x_{6,6},x_{6,7},x_{6,8}$
subject to the 9 relations
$x_{1,0}^6*[x_{1,0},x_{2,0}]*x_{4,1}^{(-1)}*x_{4,0}*[x_{5,0},x_{6,0}],\\
x_{1,1}^6*[x_{1,1},x_{2,1}]*x_{4,2}^{(-1)}*x_{4,1}*[x_{5,1},x_{6,1}],\\
x_{1,2}^6*[x_{1,2},x_{2,2}]*x_{4,3}^{(-1)}*x_{4,2}*[x_{5,2},x_{6,2}],\\
x_{1,3}^6*[x_{1,3},x_{2,3}]*x_{4,4}^{(-1)}*x_{4,3}*[x_{5,3},x_{6,3}],\\
x_{1,4}^6*[x_{1,4},x_{2,4}]*x_{4,5}^{(-1)}*x_{4,4}*[x_{5,4},x_{6,4}],\\
x_{1,5}^6*[x_{1,5},x_{2,5}]*x_{4,6}^{(-1)}*x_{4,5}*[x_{5,5},x_{6,5}],\\
x_{1,6}^6*[x_{1,6},x_{2,6}]*x_{4,7}^{(-1)}*x_{4,6}*[x_{5,6},x_{6,6}],\\
x_{1,7}^6*[x_{1,7},x_{2,7}]*x_{4,8}^{(-1)}*x_{4,7}*[x_{5,7},x_{6,7}],\\
x_{1,8}^6*[x_{1,8},x_{2,8}]*x_{3}^{(-1)}*x_{4,0}^{(-1)}*x_{3}*x_{4,8}*[x_{5,8},x_{6,8}]$

Then I set $M:=H/H^{2^6}[H^{2^5}[H,H],H]$

I know that $N$ is isomorphic to $M$ and I would like to find the isomorphism. It seems Magma can do it in principle, thanks to the function SearchForIsomorphism, but the free online version runs out of memory.

Questions:

1. Is this problem too complex for a computer algebra system running on a standard home computer?
2. Is there a free system which would allow me to do this?

Comment: [Sage](https://cloud.sagemath.com/) is free and it has some support from group theory, apparently including groups with an arbitrary finite presentation.

Comment: You can also try magma at http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/

Comment: @JairTaylor: Yes, the same is true of GAP, but after having read a lot of the manual I concluded that it cannot help me with my particular problem. I spent days finding this out and would not want to do the same with Sage...

Comment: I think the group theory in Sage consists of an interface to GAP, so it would not offer any advantages over GAP.

Comment: I am finding it too much effort to read through this post. Could you isolate the smallest or simplest  instance of your problem, and state is perhaps as a single specific problem?

Comment: @verret: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately the online memory limit is exceeded even in the smallest case.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Ok, I wrote down the smallest particular case.

Comment: In fact $N$ and $M$ are both finite $2$-groups, so it would be better to try and define them using PC-presentations and then use the function IsIsomorphic which exists in both GAP and Magma. But I am afraid that with groups with $38$ generators, there is no hope at all that this will work. There is no known algorithm for isomorphism testing of finite groups that has complexity better than $O(|G|^{d(G)})$, where $d(G)$ is the  number of generators of $G$, which is absurdly large even in the smallest of your examples.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Thanks for your opinion! And thank you for pointing out the GAP function IsIsomorphic, somehow I hadn't found that, only the Magma equivalent. In fact the quotienting out the central series group already returns a PC-representation, so that is what I tried. I will give it a try with GAP now, and then give up if it doesn't work.

Comment: Actually IsIsomorphic does not seem to exist in GAP. Finding isomorphisms seems only to work for permutation groups in GAP using the command IsomorphismGroups. I found a link here http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Software/GAP-Manual/IsIsomorphic.html claiming that a function called IsIsomorphism exists in GAP. But no such function occurs in the official manual. And GAP gives me an error message when trying to use the function.

Comment: The problem you phrase sounds hard, but not impossible. The first step probably is to represent the groups you have as pc groups. As they are (I think) p groups, you could do so by first creating the finitely presented group and then use `EpimorphismPQuotient` to find the desired groups as `Range` of the homomorphism.  Next, for the isomorphism test, there are two functions: The generic one is `IsomorphismGroups`, but there also is a probabilistic, faster, function `RandomIsomorphismTest`.

Comment: Additional comment, as I was above character limit: If you are interested in working through the steps, send me an email with the presentations in GAP syntax, and I will talk you through this.